# Monotonicity - Prove or disprove statements

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, problem-solving, monotone-functions

Can anyone help me with these questions? I have no idea how to get even started.

(Monotony) Let A, B and C be nonempty sets with total orders ≺A, ≺B and ≺C, as well as f: A → B and g: B → C. Prove or disprove the following statements.

a) If f is strictly antitone and g is strictly isotone, then g ◦ f is strictly antitone.
b) If f and g are isotone, then g ◦ f is strictly isotone.
c) If f isotone and g are injective, then g ◦ f is injective.

Comment: Always start with unabbreviated statements of the given hypotheses. These are tools that must be used. For (a) : If $x,y \in A$ then $x<_A y\implies f(x)>_B f(y).$  If $x',y'\in B$ then $x'>_By'\implies g(x')>_Cg(y').$ ..... So if $x'=f(x)$ and $y'=f(y)$ then ........ ?

Comment: For b, start by assuming a,b in A and a < b.